# Learn Microsoft Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I wanted to learn Microsoft Azure like Azure Databricks, Azure Datalake, Azure Datawarehouse. How to create these and how to use it.

Can someone please help me with any learning platform?? Where i can learn with handson

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the Microsoft Learn modules at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/ - those components do have modules there (although Datawarehouse would probably be under Synapse).